# HTML for Outlook ignoring my fixed table dimensions (even in browser)

Tags: html, css, outlook

I'm not a web guy or coder, just a sysadmin, so I'm sure I'm just making some very obvious basic mistakes. I've created an email report for our backup system but the formatting is driving me crazy. I know that Outlook creates certain restrictions - especially regarding CSS, but I can't understand why my formatting is so far out. Here is an image of a cut down version of the HTML:

[image]

The 'totals' box should line up with the 'back up type' box but when I examine the page in Chrome, I can see that the first table which has a fixed width of 900 is actually 918. Here is my HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Email Report</title>
</head>
    <body style='background-color:#dfdfdf;'>
    <table style='width:100%;text-align:left;background-color:#dfdfdf;'>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <br />
        <table border='0' cellpadding='0' width='950' align='center' style='background-color:white; border:solid #bbbbbb 1.0pt; table-layout:fixed;'>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <table border='0' width='900' cellpadding='0' align='center' style='border-collapse: collapse; table-layout:fixed;'>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td style='background-color: #ebf0f8; border: solid #dddddd 1.0pt; padding-left: 5px;' width='275'><strong><span style='font-size: 8.5pt; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; color: #444444;'>Backed up item</span></strong></td>
                      <td align='center' style='background-color: #ebf0f8; border: solid #dddddd 1.0pt;' width='65'><strong><span style='font-size: 8.5pt; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; color: #444444;'>Back up type</span></strong></td>
                      <td align='center' style='background-color: #ebf0f8; border: solid #dddddd 1.0pt;' width='70'><strong><span style='font-size: 8.5pt; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; color: #444444;'>Replica Space</span></strong></td>
                      <td align='center' style='background-color: #ebf0f8; border: solid #dddddd 1.0pt;' width='70'><strong><span style='font-size: 8.5pt; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; color: #444444;'>Recovery Space</span></strong></td>
                      <td align='center' style='background-color: #ebf0f8; border: solid #dddddd 1.0pt;' width='60'><strong><span style='font-size: 8.5pt; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; color: #444444;'>Recovery Days</span></strong></td>
                      <td align='center' style='background-color: #ebf0f8; border: solid #dddddd 1.0pt;' width='65'><strong><span style='font-size: 8.5pt; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; color: #444444;'>Recovery Points</span></strong></td>
                      <td align='center' style='background-color: #ebf0f8; border: solid #dddddd 1.0pt;' width='115'><strong><span style='font-size: 8.5pt; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; color: #444444;'>Last On-Site Backup</span></strong></td>
                      <td align='center' style='background-color: #ebf0f8; border: solid #dddddd 1.0pt;' width='115'><strong><span style='font-size: 8.5pt; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; color: #444444;'>Last Azure Backup</span></strong></td>
                      <td align='center' style='background-color: #ebf0f8; border: solid #dddddd 1.0pt;' width='65'><strong><span style='font-size: 8.5pt; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; color: #444444;'>Status</span></strong></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td style='background-color: #ffffff; border: solid #dddddd 1.0pt; border-collapse: collapse; padding-left: 5px;' width='275'><span style='font-size: 8.5pt; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; color:#444444;'>ReportServer$DPM2016TempDB</span></td>
                      <td align='center' style='background-color: #ffffff; border: solid #dddddd 1.0pt; border-collapse: collapse;' width='65'><span style='font-size: 8.5pt; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; color:#444444;'>SQL Data</span></td>
                      <td align='center' style='background-color: #ffffff; border: solid #dddddd 1.0pt; border-collapse: collapse;' width='70'><span style='font-size: 8.5pt; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; color:#444444;'>1 GB</span></td>
                      <td align='center' style='background-color: #ffffff; border: solid #dddddd 1.0pt; border-collapse: collapse;' width='70'><span style='font-size: 8.5pt; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; color:#444444;'>1 GB</span></td>
                      <td align='center' style='background-color: #ffffff; border: solid #dddddd 1.0pt; border-collapse: collapse;' width='60'><span style='font-size: 8.5pt; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; color:#444444;'>30</span></td>
                      <td align='center' style='background-color: #ffffff; border: solid #dddddd 1.0pt; border-collapse: collapse;' width='65'><span style='font-size: 8.5pt; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; color:#444444;'>30</span></td>
                      <td align='center' style='background-color: #ffffff; border: solid #dddddd 1.0pt; border-collapse: collapse;' width='115'><span style='font-size: 8.5pt; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; color:444444;'>20:01 28/01/2019</span></td>
                      <td align='center' style='background-color: #ffffff; border: solid #dddddd 1.0pt; border-collapse: collapse;' width='115'><span style='font-size: 8.5pt; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; color: #444444;'>N/A</span></td>
                      <td align='center' style='background-color: #ffffff; border: solid #dddddd 1.0pt; border-collapse: collapse;' width='65'><span style='font-size: 8.5pt; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; color:#444444;'><strong style='color:#008100;'>SUCCESS</strong></span></td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
                <table border='0' width='900' cellpadding='0' align='center' style='border-collapse: collapse;table-layout:fixed;'>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td style='background-color: #ffffff; border: solid #ffffff 1.0pt; border-collapse: collapse; padding-left: 5px;' width='275'><span style='font-size: 8.5pt; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; color: #444444;'>&nbsp;</span></td>
                      <td align='center' style='background-color: #ebf0f8; border: solid #dddddd 1.0pt; border-collapse: collapse;' width='65'><span style='font-size: 8.5pt; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; color: #444444;'>Totals</span></td>
                      <td align='center' style='background-color: #ebf0f8; border: solid #dddddd 1.0pt; border-collapse: collapse;' width='70'><span style='font-size: 8.5pt; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; color: #444444;'>6 GB</span></td>
                      <td align='center' style='background-color: #ebf0f8; border: solid #dddddd 1.0pt; border-collapse: collapse;' width='70'><span style='font-size: 8.5pt; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; color: #444444;'>12 GB</span></td>
                      <td align='center' style='background-color: #ffffff; border: solid #ffffff 1.0pt; border-collapse: collapse;' width='420'><span style='font-size: 8.5pt; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; color: #444444;'>&nbsp;</span></td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The row starting with "Totals" is contained within an entirely separate table, at the bottom of the main table.

There are a couple of options here, but the quickest fix is to simply delete the tags that end the table above and start a new table:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Email Report</title>
</head>
    <body style='background-color:#dfdfdf;'>
    <table style='width:100%;text-align:left;background-color:#dfdfdf;'>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <br />
        <table border='0' cellpadding='0' width='950' align='center' style='background-color:white; border:solid #bbbbbb 1.0pt; table-layout:fixed;'>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <table border='0' width='900' cellpadding='0' align='center' style='border-collapse: collapse; table-layout:fixed;'>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td style='background-color: #ebf0f8; border: solid #dddddd 1.0pt; padding-left: 5px;' width='275'><strong><span style='font-size: 8.5pt; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; color: #444444;'>Backed up item</span></strong></td>
                      <td align='center' style='background-color: #ebf0f8; border: solid #dddddd 1.0pt;' width='65'><strong><span style='font-size: 8.5pt; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; color: #444444;'>Back up type</span></strong></td>
                      <td align='center' style='background-color: #ebf0f8; border: solid #dddddd 1.0pt;' width='70'><strong><span style='font-size: 8.5pt; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; color: #444444;'>Replica Space</span></strong></td>
                      <td align='center' style='background-color: #ebf0f8; border: solid #dddddd 1.0pt;' width='70'><strong><span style='font-size: 8.5pt; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; color: #444444;'>Recovery Space</span></strong></td>
                      <td align='center' style='background-color: #ebf0f8; border: solid #dddddd 1.0pt;' width='60'><strong><span style='font-size: 8.5pt; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; color: #444444;'>Recovery Days</span></strong></td>
                      <td align='center' style='background-color: #ebf0f8; border: solid #dddddd 1.0pt;' width='65'><strong><span style='font-size: 8.5pt; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; color: #444444;'>Recovery Points</span></strong></td>
                      <td align='center' style='background-color: #ebf0f8; border: solid #dddddd 1.0pt;' width='115'><strong><span style='font-size: 8.5pt; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; color: #444444;'>Last On-Site Backup</span></strong></td>
                      <td align='center' style='background-color: #ebf0f8; border: solid #dddddd 1.0pt;' width='115'><strong><span style='font-size: 8.5pt; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; color: #444444;'>Last Azure Backup</span></strong></td>
                      <td align='center' style='background-color: #ebf0f8; border: solid #dddddd 1.0pt;' width='65'><strong><span style='font-size: 8.5pt; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; color: #444444;'>Status</span></strong></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td style='background-color: #ffffff; border: solid #dddddd 1.0pt; border-collapse: collapse; padding-left: 5px;' width='275'><span style='font-size: 8.5pt; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; color:#444444;'>ReportServer$DPM2016TempDB</span></td>
                      <td align='center' style='background-color: #ffffff; border: solid #dddddd 1.0pt; border-collapse: collapse;' width='65'><span style='font-size: 8.5pt; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; color:#444444;'>SQL Data</span></td>
                      <td align='center' style='background-color: #ffffff; border: solid #dddddd 1.0pt; border-collapse: collapse;' width='70'><span style='font-size: 8.5pt; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; color:#444444;'>1 GB</span></td>
                      <td align='center' style='background-color: #ffffff; border: solid #dddddd 1.0pt; border-collapse: collapse;' width='70'><span style='font-size: 8.5pt; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; color:#444444;'>1 GB</span></td>
                      <td align='center' style='background-color: #ffffff; border: solid #dddddd 1.0pt; border-collapse: collapse;' width='60'><span style='font-size: 8.5pt; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; color:#444444;'>30</span></td>
                      <td align='center' style='background-color: #ffffff; border: solid #dddddd 1.0pt; border-collapse: collapse;' width='65'><span style='font-size: 8.5pt; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; color:#444444;'>30</span></td>
                      <td align='center' style='background-color: #ffffff; border: solid #dddddd 1.0pt; border-collapse: collapse;' width='115'><span style='font-size: 8.5pt; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; color:444444;'>20:01 28/01/2019</span></td>
                      <td align='center' style='background-color: #ffffff; border: solid #dddddd 1.0pt; border-collapse: collapse;' width='115'><span style='font-size: 8.5pt; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; color: #444444;'>N/A</span></td>
                      <td align='center' style='background-color: #ffffff; border: solid #dddddd 1.0pt; border-collapse: collapse;' width='65'><span style='font-size: 8.5pt; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; color:#444444;'><strong style='color:#008100;'>SUCCESS</strong></span></td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                <!--  
                </table>
                <table border='0' width='900' cellpadding='0' align='center' style='border-collapse: collapse;table-layout:fixed;'>
                  <tbody>
                -->
                    <tr>
                      <td style='background-color: #ffffff; border: solid #dddddd 1.0pt; border-collapse: collapse; padding-left: 5px;' width='275'><span style='font-size: 8.5pt; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; color:#444444;'>&nbsp;</span></td>
                      <td align='center' style='background-color: #ebf0f8; border: solid #dddddd 1.0pt; border-collapse: collapse;' width='65'><span style='font-size: 8.5pt; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; color: #444444;'>Totals</span></td>
                      <td align='center' style='background-color: #ebf0f8; border: solid #dddddd 1.0pt; border-collapse: collapse;' width='70'><span style='font-size: 8.5pt; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; color: #444444;'>6 GB</span></td>
                      <td align='center' style='background-color: #ebf0f8; border: solid #dddddd 1.0pt; border-collapse: collapse;' width='70'><span style='font-size: 8.5pt; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; color: #444444;'>12 GB</span></td>
                      <td align='center' style='background-color: #ffffff; border: solid #ffffff 1.0pt; border-collapse: collapse;' width='420'><span style='font-size: 8.5pt; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; color: #444444;'>&nbsp;</span></td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks tshimkus. I could do that, but it won't fix the problem of the table widths not being what I set. So in this scenario, I could imagine that the full code, which may list 50 backup items across multiple servers will have each table <TD> not fully aligned with the others. Does that make sense?

Comment: Sure, but how exactly are you populating these tables? What I saw is that one table was being nested inside another, which is inadvertently inheriting some styling from the browser's default. In Chrome that automatically adds 2px to the table's `border-spacing`. You could declare your own styling across all possible browser defaults but that may become messy and difficult to control in every instance.

Comment: I have a powershell script that queries all jobs and then a foreach adds each table. These tables aren't "nested" as such, but in series aren't then? They are both nested inside a larger table though. I did try our what you suggested and the alignment is much better, almost perfect, but it doesn't make sense to me as the same changes made by the browser to table 1 should have been made to table 2, should they not?

Comment: Each table will inherit those default browser styles. The Chrome stylesheet uses `table {border-spacing: 2px;}`, which will be applied to every table unless you declare otherwise, whether in a stylesheet, `<style>` tags in the header, or inline styling attributes. Other browser rendering engines probably do their own default styling as well, I just happen to be looking at your code in Chrome.